# Can't download packages on raspberry pi?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, wheezy, roscpp, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install hydro by following the instructions on the wiki, but when I get to

`$ rosdep install  --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy`

I get

`E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-roscpp-serialization`

After some brief experimentation with apt-get, I determined that I can't seem to access any ros packages. How can I resolve this? Sorry, I'm new to linux.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134071/can%27t-download-packages-on-raspberry-pi?/) by [JumpJet27](https://answers.ros.org/users/12546/jumpjet27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easyest way to get ROS work on Raspberry is following this instruction, however it is groovy and not hydro:

https://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/06/27/getting-groovy-raspberry-pi
http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian

I have it running on the raspberry and it works well. As you are new to linux I definitely recommend first trying the groovy version, as it is much quicker and easier to set up on the raspberry (no need to build the packages from source yourself).

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) with karma: 70 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JumpJet27](https://answers.ros.org/users/12546/jumpjet27/) on 2014-02-28**:
Thanks, I was able to run it with this.